# ¿Se escriben con mayúscula los posesivos referentes a Dios y a la Virgen?

Tags: ortografía, uso-de-mayúsculas, religión

En español, escribir con mayúscula los nombres de Dios, Jesucristo y la Virgen, así como sus pronombres, no solo es habitual, sino [normativo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp) (al menos en textos religiosos):

> 4. ***Uso de mayúscula inicial independientemente de la puntuación.*** Se escriben con letra inicial mayúscula [...]
>       4.2. Los nombres de divinidades: *Dios, Jehová, Alá, Afrodita, Júpiter, Amón*.
>       4.5. Los nombres comunes [...] que se refieren, también por antonomasia, a Dios, a Jesucristo o a la Virgen: *el Creador, el Todopoderoso, el Mesías, el Salvador, la Purísima, la Inmaculada*.
>       4.20. Las advocaciones de la Virgen: *la Virgen de Guadalupe, la Virgen del Rocío*.
>       4.30. En textos religiosos, suelen escribirse con mayúscula, en señal de respeto, los pronombres personales *Tú, Ti, Sí, Vos, Él, Ella*, referidos a Dios o a la Virgen.

En inglés, además de lo anterior, también es habitual escribir en mayúscula los posesivos cuando se refieren a Dios:

> *For the Lord gives wisdom; from His mouth come knowledge and understanding.*

El caso es que yo tenía entendido que esto también era lo normal y correcto en español, y por tanto como traducción rápida y literal de lo anterior yo pondría esto:

> Porque el Señor da la sabiduría; de Su boca vienen el conocimiento y la comprensión.

Sin embargo me asalta la duda al ver que la entrada del DPD, si bien nombra el concepto genérico de "mayúscula de respeto" (la aplicada en los casos anteriores), no dice nada específico sobre los posesivos.

¿Es obligatorio, recomendado, o siquiera correcto el uso de mayúsculas en este caso?

Comment: Creo que sé de donde te ha surgido la duda ;-P Nótese que conocía la norma tanto en inglés como en español pero como ateo había elegido en mi texto no mostrar ese supuesto respeto. Salud!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece que tradicionalmente sí se ha usado la mayúscula en los posesivos para cuando se menciona a Dios. Incluso en algunos casos puede ser bastante útil, como en este ejemplo:

> *Para quien trata de Dios y de aprovechar su alma, yo no hallo otro desaguadero si no es la oración, descansar con Dios, descubrirle el corazón y hablar con Su divina Majestad como con persona que nos puede ayudar y socorrer.*
>
> San Juan Bautista de la Concepción (Juan García López), "El recogimiento interior", a 1613 (España).

Nótese como cuando dice "aprovechar su alma" no usa las mayúsculas, por lo que se refiere a la persona que "trata de Dios" y no de Dios en sí, mientras que (obviamente) "Su divina Majestad" sí se refiere a Dios.

Este uso se ha prodigado hasta tiempos más modernos:

> *Y en el bolsillo había un papel, donde el judío había escrito lo siguiente: "Yo, comerciante, de Bassra, declaro haber entregado la cantidad de mil dinares al joven Hassan Badreddin, hijo del visir Nureddin (a quien Alah haya recibido en Su misericordia), por el cargamento de la primera nave que arribe a Bassra".*
>
> Vicente Blasco Ibáñez, "Traducción de Las mil y una noches", c 1916 (España).

Se ve que también se usa para otras divinidades, siempre que sea necesario mostrar respeto. Busco otros ejemplos todavía más recientes:

> *Dios está descubriendo el propósito de Su voluntad, al igual que nosotros pasamos nuestras vidas buscando el propósito y sentido de nuestra existencia [...].*
>
> El País, 01/08/1989 : Especulaciones cósmicas

También en segunda persona:

> *Mas yo, en muchedumbre de Tu piadat,
>
>   entraré en Tu casa,
>
>   oraré en el Tu Santo Tiemplo
>
>   con temor de Ti.*
>
> Herman el Alemán, "Traslación del Psalterio", c 1240-1272 (España).

¿Un poco antiguo? ¿Qué tal este?

> *Había Jesús enviado a sus Apóstoles y discípulos a predicar, y volvían ellos gozosos, diciéndole: "Hasta los demonios mismos se sujetan a nosotros por la virtud de Tu nombre..."*
>
> C. M. de Heredia, "Una fuente de energía", 1932 (México).

No he encontrado ninguna fuente oficial, pero entiendo que el concepto de "respeto" hacia Dios se extiende a los posesivos, a juzgar por los documentos encontrados. Tal vez sea una cuestión más personal que de normativa, dado que en ocasiones, si se abusa del posesivo el texto pueda quedar un poco recargado (como ese ejemplo del siglo XIII).